# rollover images

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I am trying out simple rollover images for a site I am currently working on.  When I test the effect in firefox, the mouseover effect moves other elements on the webpage. any suggestions on how to fix this?

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
if (document.images) {
    img1 = new Image();
    img1.src = "training2.png";
} </script></head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function rollover(name, filename)
{
    var fullpath = '' + filename;
    document.images[name].src = fullpath; }
    </script>
<div id="trainingbutton"><a href="#" onmouseover="rollover('button1','training2.png');" onmouseout="rollover('button1','training.png')">
<img src="training.png" name="button1" border="0" alt="training"  /></a></div></body>
```

Comment: use same resolution of images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the previous person answered; sprites are the way to go. It takes care of having to preload the "hover" image; and it's pure CSS.

Example (an image link rollover):

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="mysprite">Join Newsletter</a>
```

Put both your non-hover and hover state images on a single canvas. If each "image" is 20px tall, the two stacked would be 40px. So to make the bottom image show, you simply **shift** the background up 20px (hence -20px on the hover state below)

CSS:

```
.mysprite {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;
    background: url('mysprite.png') no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 0; /* technically not neccesary, but illustrates the example */
    text-indent: -9999px; /* eliminates the link text so only the background image shows */
    font: 0px; /* eliminates IE displaying the text despite text-indent */

}

.mysprite:hover {
   background-position: 0 -20px;
}
```

Essentially, your creating a "mask" from which you shift the background image underneath to reveal what you want it to.

Answer (score 1):

I would not use javascript for roll over images, simply create a sprite containing both the normal state and the hover state, and then by using the hover attribute of css you can shift the background position.

Something like this:

```
<a class="rollover">Link</a>
```

And then the style:

```
a.rollover
{
    background-image:url('/images/background.png');
    background-position:top left;
}

a.rollover:hover
{
    background-position:bottom left;
}
```

This method also does not suffer from having to download the image when you rollover as it is downloaded as part of the initial request